# how to write this self join based on three columns

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join

Hello there I have a following table

```
------------------------------------------
| id | language | parentid | no_daughter |
------------------------------------------
| 1  |     1    |    0     |      2      |
------------------------------------------
| 1  |     1    |    0     |      2      |
------------------------------------------
| 2  |     1    |    1     |      1      |
------------------------------------------
| 2  |     2    |    1     |      1      |
------------------------------------------
| 3  |     1    |    1     |      0      |
------------------------------------------
| 3  |     2    |    1     |      0      |    
------------------------------------------
| 4  |     1    |    2     |      0      |
------------------------------------------
| 4  |     2    |    2     |      0      |
------------------------------------------
| 5  |     1    |    2     |      0      |
------------------------------------------
| 5  |     2    |    2     |      1      |
-----------------------------------------
| 5  |     1    |    4     |      1      |
------------------------------------------
| 5  |     2    |    4     |      1      |
------------------------------------------
```

**Scenario**

Every record has more than one rows in table with different `language` ids. `parentid` tells who is the parent of this record. `no_daughter` columns tells against each record that how many child one record has. Means in Ideal scenario If `no_daughter` has value `2` of `id = 1` , it means `1` should be `parentid` of 2 records in same table. **But If a record has more than one exitance with respect to language, it will be considered as one record**.

**My Problem**

I need to find out those records where `no_daughter` value is not correct. It means if `no_daughter` is 2, there must be two records whoes `parentid` has that id. In above case record with `id = 1` is valid. But record having `id = 2` is not valid because the `no_daughter = 1` but actual daughter of this record is 2. Same is the case with `id=4`

Can any body tell me how can I find these faulty records?

**Updated after answers**

Ken Clark has and shola has given answer which return same result for example shola query is

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
id 
FROM
tbl_info t 
INNER JOIN 
  (SELECT 
    parentid,
    COUNT(DISTINCT id) AS childs 
  FROM
    tbl_info 
  GROUP BY parentid) AS parentchildrelation 
  ON t.id = parentchildrelation.parentid 
  AND t.no_daughters != parentchildrelation.childs
```

This query is returning those ids who have been used as `parentid` somewhere in table but having wrong `no_daughter` values. But not returning ids that has value in `no_daugter` columns but have not been used as `parentid` any where in table. For exampl `id = 5` has `no_daughter = 1` but it is not used as `parentid` in table. So it is also a faulty record. But above query is not capturing such records.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
      id 
FROM
   tbl_info t 
Left JOIN 
   (SELECT 
       parentid,
       COUNT(DISTINCT id) AS childs 
   FROM
       tbl_info 
   GROUP BY parentid) AS parentchildrelation 
   ON t.id = parentchildrelation.parentid 
  Where t.no_daughters != parentchildrelation.childs
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT id FROM tinfo t inner join
(SELECT parentid, COUNT(distinct language ) as childs FROM tinfo group by parentid) as     summary
on t.id=summary.parentid and t.no_daughters!= summary.childs
```

Comment: no dear in consistent result. Means not returning actual result

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 Select Distinct * From tablename t
 Left Join
 (
   Select COUNT(t1.Id) Doughter,t1.parentid,t1.language From tablename  t1 Group By t1.parentid,t1.language
 )tbl
 On t.id=tbl.parentid And tbl.language=t.language And t.no_daughter<>tbl.Doughter
```

Comment: I have updaetd my question. Please have a look

Comment: Change inner join to left join to get ids that has value in no_daugter columns but have not been used as parentid any where in table. Thanks. Answer updated.